# VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-virtualized

I have an issue with a FlatList that receives no more than 10 items.

This is the code for the FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    style={styles.flatList}
    onScroll={(event) => toggleHeader(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > headerHeight)}
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: getContentContainerStyle() }}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    onRefresh={makeRequest}
    refreshing={isRefreshing}
    data={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item?.id?.toString()}
/>
```

The flow in the application is at follows:

The application is using tab bar navigation, and a single component is used that is making a request with a specific id for every tab to get the correct data from DB.

My **renderItem** method is a long stack of **if elses** to check item type to know that to render because there can be multiple types of items, but the number of them is really small (like 10-15 maximum). Some items are **horizontal FlatLists** but also the number of items in them are like 2-4.

After changing the tabs fora couple a times, this VirtualizedList warning is thrown, but my items are correctly showed in the correct number and order.

I am using functional components and hooks.

Tried adding `maxToRenderPerBatch` and `initialNumToRender` but it doesn't work.

I don't want to change my **renderItem** in a PureComponent because my list will always have a few items so I am trying to understand why it throws this warning.

**EDIT**

This issues happens only on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Add your all child **Scrollview** in your case **FlatList**:

`<FlatList nestedScrollEnabled={true}/>`

Comment: I tried to add this property on all my FlatLists that are somehow nested as item in my big FlatList and also on the big FlatList but is still throwing on iOS
thank you for your time